# How can I programmatically discover a Win32::OLE object's properties and methods in Perl?

Tags: perl, com, win32ole

With Perl, it's quite easy using the [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE) library to load up COM/OLE objects and control them.  The issue I'm running into is knowing exactly what methods and properties are available in the object I'm accessing.  Some OLE toolkits in other languages can generate a static interface for you by reading all of the properties and methods that are available on the object.  Does such a facility exist with Perl's `Win32::OLE` library?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should access the properties from the `Win32::OLE` object's keys directly. Let's use Excel as the example. The code is from Win32::OLE examples - properties.pl
It will show all properties of an `Win32::OLE` object.

```
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
# Add a workbook to get some more property values defined
$Excel->Workbooks->Add;
print "OLE object's properties:\n";
foreach my $Key (sort keys %$Excel) {
    my $Value;

    eval {$Value = $Excel->{$Key} };
    $Value = "***Exception***" if $@;

    $Value = "<undef>" unless defined $Value;

    $Value = '['.Win32::OLE->QueryObjectType($Value).']' 
      if UNIVERSAL::isa($Value,'Win32::OLE');

    $Value = '('.join(',',@$Value).')' if ref $Value eq 'ARRAY';

    printf "%s %s %s\n", $Key, '.' x (40-length($Key)), $Value;
}
```

In one line, to get all properties of a Win32::OLE object:

```
keys %$OleObject;
```

All OLE methods can be retrieved via `Win32::OLE::TypeInfo`. this block of code will print all the method names of $OleObject:

```
my $typeinfo = $OleObject->GetTypeInfo();
my $attr = $typeinfo->_GetTypeAttr();
for (my $i = 0; $i< $attr->{cFuncs}; $i++) {
    my $desc = $typeinfo->_GetFuncDesc($i);
    # the call conversion of method was detailed in %$desc
    my $funcname = @{$typeinfo->_GetNames($desc->{memid}, 1)}[0];
    say $funcname;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing is for sure, if you do this:

```
print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $my_ole_object ] )
```

you'll likely only get an endless loop. But you can modify it like this:

```
local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 2;
print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $my_ole_object ] )
```

And then you can at least see the property names. To see their next level of values, you will need `Maxdepth=3`. I'm not exactly sure how to look at all the methods other than documentation.

Answer (score 1):

No. but it looks like the necessary type discovery code is [already in Win32::OLE's implementation](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDB/Win32-OLE-0.1709/OLE.xs). You can use it as a reference to write your own perl extension that exposes function and method types and names.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ActiveState, there is OLE Browser included (available in Start menu). It requires you to enable *"Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe"* security setting of the *"Local intranet"* zone, but generally it works well and gives you list of all properties and methods along with its types.

Another good source is documentation in individual applications - MS applications usually come with VBA docs. Note that object model described in those apps is the same OLE links to.